# App crashes when loses focus

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

When I open my app from the winrt screen, it's main page takes some time to load (around a minute as I have written some code that takes time). Mean while if I navigate to my desktop and then return back to the app, the app crashes and I have to open the app again from the winrt screen and wait till the app loads the main page.

**Only after the main page has completely loaded I can navigate to my desktop and then return and the app does not crash. If I navigate while the main page is loading I face this problem of app crashing.**

Can I know the reason why it happens and how do I prevent it from crashing? I have developed the app in `Xaml+C#` in `visual studio 2012` (Windows store app) My app also has passed the test.

Comment: Are you not getting any exception ?

Comment: I don't get any Exception when I am running it from Visual Studio 2012, It neither crashes it correctly resumes but when I run it in another machine or my machine only from the winrt screen this issue comes up.

Comment: If it is possible, can you give me your project, so I can inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to desktop, your application will be put to "suspended" state(code does not run) and it will be executed further when you reactivate your application.

Are you loading stuff from web? Wrap everything into try/catch and see where the exception comes from.

Comment: I am using a wrapper that connects to a database and pulls data. When application is suspended the code does not run, so once the application resumes the code continues to run or should I explicitly make a connection every time the app resumes? Is there a way where I can pull the data from the DB when the app is not in focus?

Comment: I don't get any Exception when I am running it from Visual Studio 2012, It neither crashes it correctly resumes but when I run it in another machine or my machine only from the winrt screen this issue comes up.